# Javascript: How to scroll through pictures with an incrementor?

Tags: javascript, html

I am extremely new to web programming, so please be patient as I am sure this is a basic question.  I studied HTML and CSS, and began Javascript yesterday.  I am unable to get this code to run correctly.

The way I was thinking to design it is to have a series of pictures 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc and it would show one picture at a time.  When you click a button it would go to the next picture using an incrementor.

I am looking first of all to make this work with as few changes as possible so I can see what I messed up on (learning and all that) and then I am sure there are shortcuts I could use which I'd love to learn.  Please help if you can.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var picount=1;
document.write("<center>");
document.write("<img src=" + picount + ".jpg>");
document.write("</center>");

function upCount()
{
picount=picount+1;
}
</script>
<br><br><center>
<input type="button" onclick="upCount()" value="Next Picture" /></center>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `.src` property on the image so it will load a new image.  Here's one way to do that:

```
<script>
var picount=1;
document.write("<center>");
document.write("<img id='picture' src=" + picount + ".jpg>");
document.write("</center>");

function upCount() {
    picount=picount+1;
    document.getElementById('picture').src = picount + ".jpg";
}
</script>
<br><br><center>
<input type="button" onclick="upCount()" value="Next Picture" /></center>
```

---

And, in this code, there's really no reason to use `document.write()` to write out the initial HTML.  It might as well be static HTML in the page like this:

```
<script>
var picount=1;

function upCount() {
    ++picount;
    document.getElementById('picture').src = picount + ".jpg";
}
</script>
<center>
<img id="picture" src="1.jpg">
</center>
<br><br><center>
<input type="button" onclick="upCount()" value="Next Picture" /></center>
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I edited the code and it worked perfectly.  Is there a way to make it cycle back around if I only have 5 pictures, so 1.jpg to 5.jpg?

Comment: @ChrisDavis - yes, that would be easy.  Is that not something you could do yourself just by modifying the `upCount()` function?  What would you need help with to implement that?  If you can't tell, I'd rather you try on your own and when you get stuck you tell us what you got stuck on rather than I just hand you the code for that enhancement.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure.  Let me give it some thought.